# Compiling with c++ and getting "ready to go" executable

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, shared-libraries

Is it possible to compile a program with g++ so that shared libraries etc are "included" with the executable?

I have a c++ program that I'd like to compile and run at another location where I'm missing some libraries and don't have install access.

The main reason I couldn't find answers for this is probably that I don't know how to call it..

Comment: I think you need to compile (and link) using the static version of the libraries. If you have only dynamic libraries you have to try to re-compile those to be static libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Either link statically (with `-static`) so it doesn't use any shared libraries, or copy the shared libraries to the other location along with the executable.

Since the shared libraries will not be in the dynamic loader's usual search paths you'll need to ensure they can be found, either by setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable when running the program, or by setting an RPATH in the executable when you build it.

(Assuming you're using the GNU linker ...) To set an RPATH in the executable link with `'-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN'` (the quotes are important, to stop `$ORIGIN` being expanded by the shell). That means the loader will look for shared libraries in the same directory as the executable itself.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dynamic_or_shared.html#manual.intro.using.linkage.dynamic for more information.

Comment: @jorgen When following Jonathans advice and installing the shared libs in the same dir as your app, you can test it by starting your executable with `$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.;${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} ./<appname>` (which temporarily adds the current working dir to the path).